# Should methods handle nulls? best practice in this case?

Tags: c#, parameters, null

I have the following situation in code, whats the best way to manage it, the comments contains the situations, and please recommend the best practice.

```
try
{
    string errorMessage = AccountClient.GetAccount(id, out accountDetails);

    // FIRST WAY : REMOVE THIS NULL CHECK AT ALL AND LEAVE GetAccountDetails to control
    // the Null situation?
    if (accountDetails == null)
    {
        // Second Way: This way? Throw exception here?
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accountDetails));
        //Third way? break the function?
        break;
    }

    // GetAccount Details already has null control
    Subscription subscription = AccountProcessor.GetAccountDetails(accountDetails);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: If null is not an expected value, then just throw an exception. There is no point in continuing if all your assumptions are broken.  And simply breaking out of the method without throwing would likely end up causing an error somewhere else up the call stack, making it that much harder to debug the cause of the problem.

Comment: Note that `break` does not "break the function", it breaks out of the surrounding loop.

Comment: It looks like `AccountClient.GetAccount` should throw an exception if it fails instead of returning an error message.

Comment: Thanks, what is the elegant way to leave a try catch block?

Comment: If you can do anything about a null then handle it. if not just call `GetAccountDetails` and let it decide what should happen.

Comment: don't break the function, keep it intact

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. It's reasonable and clear, plus an answer may be given even if it's not about an error but about style. Moreover you will see this kind of code very often a d if it may help someone else in future to avoid bad patterns...

Comment: My question is: As a separation of concerns is not more elegant than every subsequent method handle nulls instead of having logic to handle nulls outside of the methods itself?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the costruction

```
catch (Exception e) {
  throw; 
}
```

is *redundant* one and can be *eliminated*. Now about `null`s. There're two 
cases:

- `null` is an *erroneous* value and so it should be *signalled*
- `null` is an *expected*, *ordinary* value and thus it should be *proceeded*

And so you have (`null` is an error)

```
string errorMessage = AccountClient.GetAccount(id, out accountDetails);

// What's wrong: it's id which doesn't correspond to any detail 
// (we expect id being s.t. AccountClient.GetAccount(id...) returns not null detail)
if (accountDetails == null) 
  throw new ArgumentException($"Incorrect id {id} which doesn't have any detail.", 
                              nameof(id));

Subscription subscription = AccountProcessor.GetAccountDetails(accountDetails);
```

Or (`null` is an expected outcome)

```
string errorMessage = AccountClient.GetAccount(id, out accountDetails);

if (accountDetails == null)
  return null; // or any reasonable value, or just return, or create new Subscription

Subscription subscription = AccountProcessor.GetAccountDetails(accountDetails);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can do anything about null input then handle it.

```
try
{
    string errorMessage = AccountClient.GetAccount(id, out accountDetails);

    if (accountDetails == null)
    {
         // do something about it. Maybe write some logs, substitute with a default value
         // or throw appropriate exception ...
    }

    Subscription subscription = AccountProcessor.GetAccountDetails(accountDetails);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw;
}
```

if you can't then let `GetAccountDetails` decide what should happen.

```
try
{
    string errorMessage = AccountClient.GetAccount(id, out accountDetails);
    Subscription subscription = AccountProcessor.GetAccountDetails(accountDetails);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw;
}
```

Also there is no need to catch an exception, doing nothing and then `throw` it so you can remove the whole try catch block.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where this ID is coming from. If the user typed the ID, then I wouldn't generate an Exception, since it is not a error in your program. Just treat the user input and show a proper message. Exceptions are costly, so I usually use them only when i have a real programa failure. Besides that, if you write a custom Exception Handler, it wouldn`t make sense to log a error caused by wrong user input. So i would make it like this:

```
if (AccountClient.AccountExists(id))
{
    AccountDetails details = AccountClient.GetAccount(id);
    Subscription subscription = AccountProcessor.GetAccountDetails(accountDetails);
}
```

Anyway, its good to treat the input on the same way, even if you had treated like above, in case there is any other non treated call to it:

```
public AccountDetails GetAccount(int id)
{
    if (Exists(id))
        GetTheAccount(id);
    else
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Account {0} doesn't exists", id));
}
```

In this case I would use an Exception because it could really represent an error, if the caller function is passing a wrong value, for instance.